# Should I use a custom 'locks' table with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, locks

I'm developing a relatively simple, custom web app with a MySQL MyISAM database on the back end. Somehow, I want to avoid the classic concurrency overwrite problem, e.g. that user A overwrites user B's edits because B loads and submits some edit form before A is finished.

That's why I would like to somehow lock a row on displaying the edit form. However...

- As I said, I'm using MyISAM, which, as far as I can tell, doesn't support row-level locks. Also, I'm not sure if holding 'real' MySQL locks for a couple of minutes is recommended practice.
- I don't really know much about transactions, but from what I've seen, it looks like they're meant to be used inside one connection.
- Using some kind of conflict merge system like Git has is not an option really.

Rows would stay locked for a few minutes. Concurrency is very low: there's half a dozen users using the app at any time.

I'm now planning on using a table with details on which user is doing what, and since when. The app can then decide to not show the edit form when some other user recently opened it (e.g. is working on it). This fake lock would be deleted on saving the form.

Would this work? What should I do to avoid deadlocks, livelocks and all that stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a lock, the easiest would probably be adding two fields to the data you want locked (lock_created Datetime, locked_by int). Then on the edit page (and probably also on the edit button) you check wether (lock_created + lock_interval) < now() - if not, the data is locked for editing and the user should be informed. (Note you always need the check on the edit-page, not just on the edit button.)
Also on the submission page, you need to check the user still has the lock to submit. (See below.)

The one difficult part of this is what to do when someone edits but fails to submit within the lock interval. 
So:

1. The lock_interval is 2 minutes.
2. At time 0:00 Alice locks the page, edits something, but gets a phone call and doesn't submit her changes
3. At time 2:30 Bob checks the page, gets the edit lock because Alice's lock has expired, and edits
4. At time 3:00 Alice gets back to her comp, presses submit -> conflict.

Someone doesn't get their data submitted. There is no way around that if you set locks to expire. (And if you don't, locks can be left forever.) 
You can only decide which one to give priority (going with the new lock created by Bob is probably easiest) and inform the other the page has expired and the data won't be sumbitted, and hand them back their edits to redo them.

A note on the table structure: you could create a table 'locks' with fields 'table_name, row_id, lock_created, locked_by' but it probably won't be the easiest way, since joining on variable table names is complex and confusing. Also, there is probably no use to have a single place for all locks to be stored. For a simple mechanism, I think adding uniform fields to every table you want to implement the locking mechanism is easier all around.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I think I'll be going with rather short expire times and refresh them somehow with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely not use row-level locks for this scenario.

You can use optimistic locking, which basically means that you have a version field for each row, which is incremented when the row is saved. Before save you make sure that the version field is the same as what it was when the row was loaded, which means that noone else has saved anything since you read the row.

Comment: But then what would you do with the 'newest' version, i.e. the one that would otherwise overwrite the 'semi-new' version? Failing if the row was edited by someone else in the meantime would mean one of the user's changes is lost.